# can two dis assemblers produce different dis assembly for the same executable?

Tags: assembly, decompiling, disassembly

I have an executable which I am dis assembling using two different dis assemblers. I am of the knowledge that the instructions may be different but the opcodes have to be same in both the dis assemblies. But I observe that the opcodes are not same. Is there any specific reason for that? Does it depend on dis assemblers?

Answer (score 2):

There could be many reasons why two disassemblers produces different output.

Wrong opcode parsing, replacing opcodes with macros, anti-disassembly tricks (such as 'jump' or 'call' to middle of opcode), difficulties in parsing swich-case code, wrong recognition of processor architecture version, ignoring "meaningless" opcodes, wrong alignment, wrong identify of procedures beginning, wrong parsing of file holder and there are so many more... Each of those may result in different output.

If you are interested here is another interesting thing but on the other direction:
http://accessomat.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/x86-assembler-is-not-injective/

Comment: There may be much simpler reasons. E.g. `je` and `jz` are two mnemonics for the same opcode.